# Binding a property to Page.Transitions in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app with two pages and I have specified my page transition like so:

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition x:Name="MyTransition" FromHorizontalOffset="500"/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

And this works as expected.
Also, if I change the property in the code-behind like so:

```
MyTransition.FromHorizontalOffset = 500;
```

It also works. However, if I try to bind to a property in a ViewModel, like so:

```
<EntranceThemeTransition x:Name="MyTransition" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding Path=TransitionValue}"/>
```

Or even like so:

```
<EntranceThemeTransition x:Name="MyTransition" FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding ElementName=MyPageView, Path=DataContext.TransitionValue}"/>
```

The value is not set and acts as if nothing is there running with the default values.


So my question is, can I bind a property to Page.Transitions element?

Comment: maybe issue with view model? Do you tried binding another element, value ?

Comment: Yes, I have the ViewModel properly working with other properties.

Comment: This is a race condition.